# Real time table alternative vs swapping table

Tags: sql-server, real-time, compare-and-swap, merge-statement, indexed-views

I use SSMS 2016. I have a view that has a few millions of records. The view is not indexed and should not be as it's being updated (insert, delete, update) every 5 minutes by a job on the server to then display update data sets in to the client calling application in GUI.

The view does a very heavy volume of conversion INT values to VARCHAR appending to them some string values.

The view also does some CAST operations on the NULL assigning them column names aliases. And the worst performance hit is that the view uses FOR XML PATH('') function on 20 columns.

Also the view uses two CTEs as the source as well as Subsidiaries to define a single column value.

I made sure I created the right indexes (Clustered, nonclustered,composite and Covering) that are used in the view Select,JOIN,and WHERE clauses.

Database Tuning Advisor also have not suggested anything that could substantialy improve performance.

AS a workaround I decided to create two identical physical tables with clustered indexes on each and using the Merge statement (further converted into a SP and then Into as SQL Server Agent Job) maintain them updated. And to assure there is no long locking of the view. I will then swap(rename) the tables names immediately after each merge finishes. So in this case all the heavy workload falls onto a SQL Server Agent Job keep the tables updated.

The problem is that the merge will take roughly 15 minutes considering current size of the data, which may increase in the future. So, I need to have a real time design to assure that the view has the most up-to-date information.

Any ideas?

Comment: In-memory table?

Comment: You say the view has a few million rows, but do you need to read them each time? I have often see such heavy views which are used in complex queries and only small part of their rows are selected. If you do not need all the rows when the view is query, you can wrap it in inline-table-valued function and pass some filtering parameters based on which filtering indexes can be created, too.

Comment: Actually  gotqn you were right. The Job does not need to read all the records from the view, but instead of it joins to the Audit table. And seems like my current view uses CTEs entirely before starting filtering the view columns.